# Django template tag argument count error

Tags: python, django, git, django-templates

I have a project running on Django 1.6 that is being developed on local machines with a git repo on BitBucket.

We have some test environments running on a server where we then checkout the repo and run the software.

---

When loading the login page one of the test environments presents the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /login/
breadcrumbs requires 0 arguments, 1 provided
In template /.../templates/includes/breadcrumbs.html, error at line 6
```

The project contains the following code:

**admin/login.html**

```
{% extends "workflow/base_site.html" %}
<!-- ... -->
{% block breadcrumbs %}{% endblock %}
```

**workflow/base_site.html**

```
{% extends "workflow/base.html" %}
<!-- ... -->
{% block breadcrumbs %}
    {% include "includes/breadcrumbs.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

**breadcrumbs.html**

```
{% load tags %}
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    {% if crumbs %}
        {{ crumbs | breadcrumbs:current_object_id | safe }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**tags.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def breadcrumbs(obj=None, current_object_id=None):
    # ...
    pass
```

---

The `login.html` template extends the `workflow/base_site.html` but overrides the `breadcrumbs` block, and shouldn't be including `breadcrumbs.html`.

For the login page the `breadcrumbs.html` template is not expected to have a context variable named `crumbs`, and shouldn't be calling the `breadcrumbs()` tag.

The errors are only occurring in one of out test environments, i.e. the same code runs on the same machine under a different user account.

Is anyone able to identify the cause of this problem?

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks for the tip, it helped identify an orphan `tags.pyc` file from when the tags were placed in a different directory.  If you want to post your comment as an answer I would like to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have another filter named `breadcrumbs` in your project. Try renaming yours to something else to check.

It can also be a compiled `.pyc` file, as you later found out.